# Can we use synchronised for run() method in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

As we know there is no provision to prevent more than one thread calling the `run()` method by using `start()` method. I did create two objects `m1` and `m2` both calling the same thread to run.

I need to make sure the first object finishes (`m1.start`) its execution by calling thread before second object execution starts.

My question is why can't i use `synchronized` keyword with `run()` method in the thread that I have created (i.e. `MyThread1`)?

I tried using "synchronized" to run() method in the thread that I have created but it gives arbitrary output (in other words `m2` doesn't wait for the `m1` to finish execution).

You can see at the very bottom of the program the output that I am getting.

```
public class ExtendedThreadDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Mythread1 m1 =new Mythread1();
        Mythread1 m2 =new Mythread1();
        m1.start();
        m2.start();
        System.out.println(" main thread exiting ....");
    }
}
```

#### MyThread

```
public class MyThread1 extends Thread {

    public synchronized void run() {
        for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.println(" inside the mythread-1 i = "+ i);
            System.out.println(" finish ");

            if (i%2 == 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                     System.out.println(" the thread has been interrupted ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
main thread exiting ....
inside the mythread-1 i = 1
finish
inside the mythread-1 i = 2
finish 
inside the mythread-1 i = 1
finish 
inside the mythread-1 i = 2
finish 
inside the mythread-1 i = 3
finish 
inside the mythread-1 i = 4
finish 
inside the mythread-1 i = 3
finish 
inside the mythread-1 i = 4
finish
```

As you can see after `i = 2`, second object (i.e. `m2.start()`) started executing.

Comment: if you want to have it synchronized, why do you need it to be in class which extends thread? Just move it to separate one.

Comment: There is **zero** point in having the run method synchronized. What, you want to start 5 threads, so that they can wait for each other to finish? This is exactly the same as having one thread executing that `run` five times in a row, just with more overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Call `m1.join()` in `main` before calling `m2.start()`.

Making methods `synchronized` only affects multiple calls to methods on the *same* object; `m1` and `m2` are different objects, so adding `synchronized` will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you Louis. I will not or wont be able to call same instance ex: m1.start and again m1.start...java wont allow multiple calls to same method

Comment: please ignore top comment ..Thank you Louis. I will not or wont be able to call same thread start() instance twice in java  ex: m1.start and again calling m1.start .if i try to call twice the second will throw IllegalThreadStateException. if i agree with you I wont be able to see synchronized working in my program because as stated above i will get IllegalThreadStateException on the second call. I am coming back to you becuase you said "making methods synchronized only affects calls to methds on the same object". i will be greatfull if you help me understand this synchronised concept.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you call `start` twice on the same thread.  What gave you that idea?  I'm saying that you should write `m1.start(); m1.join(); m2.start();`

Comment: Thank You Louis...I have executed as what you said and it is doing right job as expected. what is bothering me and making me to think over and over is your first suggestion "Making methods synchronized only affects multiple calls to methods on the same object" ...("multiple calls to methods on same object..." ). will be there multiple calls to methods of a thread ?

Comment: No, that's the point. `run` is the only method, and it'll get called only once.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet:

```
public synchronized void run() {
  //code
}
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
public void run() {
  synchronized(this) {
    //code
  }
}
```

Note the `this` reference. This means that all `synchronized` blocks using the same `this` reference (lock object) are mutually exclusive. However you are creating two threads (objects), each is synchronizing on a different `this` reference.

There are several ways to improve your code:

#### Use only one `Runnable` and create two threads:

```
public class Mythread1 implements Runnable //...
```

and then:

```
Runnable r = new Mythread1();
Thread m1 = new Thread(r);
Mythread1 m2 = new Thread(r);
```

But this will only work if `Mythread1` runnable is statelss as it will be shared by two threads.

#### Use the same lock instance

Pass some arbitrary `lock` object to both instances of `Mythread1` and then use:

```
synchronized(lock) {
  //code
}
```

Starting from Java 5 there are much more sophisticated ways of synchronizing code, but this one is fine for simple cases.

#### Use `Thread.join()`

You can call:

```
m1.start();
m1.join();
m2.start();
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Can you as a bonus point out any kind of reason to use treads like that? :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: you mean `start`/`join`/`start()` sequence? Well, a possible reason is to start one task, do some processing in main thread, wait for that task to finish (`join`) and continue with the second one, having results of both foreground processing and first task.

Comment: But why start a new thread each time, instead of reuse the one that just finished a task? I guess it kind of made half a sense before `java.util.concurrent` simply because it was easier to code than a proper solution that reuses one background thread. Anyways, sorry to barge in like that, I don't want to start a flame :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: you are absolutely right. But OP doesn't seem to understand how `synchronized` keyword work (yet), so introducing more abstract solutions like thread pools might not be a good idea now (well, teaching bad patterns is not good either...)

Comment: A lightweight improvement (without Executors) would be to employ a `CyclicBarrier`.

Answer (score 0):

A synchronized instance method only hinder concurrent access to the same instance of the class. You would see your expected effect if the run method was static. But I do not suggest making the run method static. In fact you cannot if it is to keep its current functionality. What you should instead consider is using `m1.join()` to wait for m1 to finish. Another approach which works better if you have multiple threads which are to wait for each other is to use a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: I will not or wont be able to call same thread start() instance twice in java ex: m1.start and again calling m1.start .if i try to call twice the second will throw IllegalThreadStateException. if i agree with you I wont be able to see synchronized working in my program because as stated above i will get IllegalThreadStateException on the second call. i will get IllegalThreadStateException on the second call. I am coming back to you becuase you said "A synchronized instance method only hinder concurrent access to the same instance of the class." thank you